# Pythonic and efficient way to do an elementwise "in" using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I'm looking for a way to efficiently get an array of booleans, where given two arrays with equal size `a` and `b`, each element is true if the corresponding element of `a` appears `in` the corresponding element of `b`.

For example, the following program:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = numpy.array([[1, 2, 13], [2, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7]])
print(numpy.magic_function(a, b))
```

Should print

```
[True, True, False, False]
```

Keep in mind this function should be the equivalent of

```
[x in y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Only `numpy`-optimized for cases when `a` and `b` are big, and each element of `b` is reasonably small.

Comment: Aside: if you care about efficiency, you shouldn't be using an array like your `b`: instead of a fast numpy 2D array of int dtype you only have a 1D array of object dtype.

Comment: To be fair, the brunt of the work (checking if an integer is in a numpy array) is handled by your list comprehension. That may be the most efficient (and definitely the most Pythonic) way to do it.

Comment: @Kupiakos Good point, I forgot to add that the usecase I'm looking for this is for big `a` and `b`, and each element of `b` having few elements.

Comment: Based on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html, I think you want to use nditer or maybe in1d http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d.

Comment: @BBrown `in1d` would only work if all elements of `b` were equal. `nditer` seems too complicate dfor this usecase.

Comment: Since the elements of `b` differ in length, there's little point in it being an array.  Either turn  it into a real 2d array, or treat it as a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take advantage of NumPy's [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules you should make array `b` squared first, which can be achieved using `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

c = np.array(list(izip_longest(*b))).astype(float)
```

resulting in:

```
array([[  1.,   2.,   5.,   7.],
       [  2.,   8.,   6.,  nan],
       [ 13.,   9.,  nan,  nan]])
```

Then, by doing `np.isclose(c, a)` you get a 2D array of Booleans showing the difference between each `c[:, i]` and `a[i]`, according to the broadcasting rules, giving:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Which can be used to obtain your answer:

```
np.any(np.isclose(c, a), axis=0)
#array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there an upper limit to the length of the small lists in `b`? If so, maybe you could make `b` a matrix of say 1000x5, and use `nan` to fill the gaps for the sub-arrays that are too short. You can then use [numpy.any](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to get the answer you want, something like this:

```
In [42]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    ...: b = np.array([[1, 2, 13], [2, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7]])

In [43]: bb = np.full((len(b), max(len(i) for i in b)), np.nan)

In [44]: for irow, row in enumerate(b):
    ...:     bb[irow, :len(row)] = row

In [45]: bb
Out[45]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,  13.],
       [  2.,   8.,   9.],
       [  5.,   6.,  nan],
       [  7.,  nan,  nan]])

In [46]: a[:,np.newaxis] == bb
Out[46]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [47]: np.any(a[:,np.newaxis] == bb, axis=1)
Out[47]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

No idea if this is faster for your data.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

The approach from Sauldo Castro runs most quickly among those posted so far. The generator expression in the original post is second fastest.

## Code to generate test data:

```
import numpy
import random

alength = 100
a = numpy.array([random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(alength)])
b = []
for i in range(alength):
    length = random.randint(1, 5)
    element = []
    for i in range(length):
        element.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    b.append(element)
b = numpy.array(b)
print a, b
```

## The options:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def magic_function1(a, b): # From OP Martin Fixman
    return [x in y for x, y in zip(a, b)]  

def magic_function2(a, b): # What I thought might be better.
    bools = []
    for x, y in zip(a,b):
        found = False
        for j in y:
            if x == j:
                found=True
                break
        bools.append(found)

def magic_function3(a, b): # What I tried first
    bools = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        found = False
        for j in range(len(b[i])):
            if a[i] == b[i][j]:
                found=True
                break
        bools.append(found)

def magic_function4(a, b): # From Bas Swinkels
    bb = numpy.full((len(b), max(len(i) for i in b)), numpy.nan)
    for irow, row in enumerate(b):
        bb[irow, :len(row)] = row
    a[:,numpy.newaxis] == bb
    return numpy.any(a[:,numpy.newaxis] == bb, axis=1)

def magic_function5(a, b): # From Sauldo Castro, revised version
    c = numpy.array(list(izip_longest(*b))).astype(float)
    return numpy.isclose(c, a), axis=0)
```

## Time n_executions

```
n_executions = 100
clock = timeit.Timer(stmt="magic_function1(a, b)", setup="from __main__ import magic_function1, a, b")
print clock.timeit(n_executions), "seconds"
# Repeat with each candidate function
```

## The results:

- 0.158078225475 seconds for magic_function1
- 0.181080926835 seconds for magic_function2
- 0.259621047822 seconds for magic_function3
- 0.287054750224 seconds for magic_function4
- 0.0839162196207 seconds for magic_function5