# Is there a vectorized way to check whether the ith element of a 1D array is present on the ith element of a 3D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D array of length *k* with some arbitrary values and a 3D array of dimensions *k* * *i* * *j* with some data.

```py
import numpy as np

# create 1D and 3D array
values = np.array([2, 5, 1], dtype=np.int)
arr = np.zeros((3, 4, 4), dtype=np.int)

# insert some random numbers in the 3D array
arr[0, 3, 2] = 5
arr[1, 1, 1] = 2
arr[2, 2, 3] = 1
```

```
>>> print(values)
[2 5 1]

>>> print(arr)
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 5 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 2 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
```

My goal is to determine if the i<sup>th</sup> element of `values` (*i.e.* a scalar) is present in the i<sup>th</sup> element of `arr` (*i.e.* a 2D array) and get a boolean array of length *k*.

In my example, I would expect to get an array `[False, False, True]` as `1` is the only number present in its correspondent 2D array (`arr[2]`).

As `np.isin` function is not an option, I have come up with two possible solutions so far.

1) Create a 3D array by repeating the numbers in `values` and then do an elementh-wise comparison:

```py
rep = np.ones(arr.shape) * values.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

```py
>>> print(rep)
[[[2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2.]]

 [[5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]]

>>> np.any((arr == rep), axis=(1, 2))
array([False, False,  True])
```

However, this approach seems like a bad idea from a memory perspective if both `values` and `arr` have bigger shapes.

2) Iterate over each value in `values` and check if it is present in its correspondent 2D array of `arr`.

```py
result = []
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    result.append(value in arr[i])
```

```
>>> print(result)
[False, False, True]
```

This approach is of course better from a memory perspective but again, when implemented with bigger arrays it can become time consuming (think of *k* being 1000000 instead of 3).

Is there any other `numpy` function I am missing or perhaps a better approach to accomplish my goal here?

I already took a look at the answers to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618336/pythonic-and-efficient-way-to-do-an-elementwise-in-using-numpy) but they do not fit my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) might help:

```
np.any(values[:,None,None] == arr, axis=(1,2))
```

is a one liner that gives `[False,False,True]`.  note that if you're storing `arr` then storing a similar `bool` array shouldn't be too bad

note that it's the `values[:,None,None] == arr` that's doing the broasting, strange [indexing with `None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) being equivalent to your `reshape` (but feels more idiomatic to me)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that your problem is equivalent to

```
[np.any(arr[i]==values[i]) for i in range(len(values))]
```

I agree this is time consuming. Elementwise comparison can't be avoided here so `np.any(arr[i]==values[i])` or `values[i] in arr[i]` is must-do here. What about vectorizations, I found it quite difficult to replace list comprehension used here too. This is my way using [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
def myfunc(i): return np.any(arr[i]==values[i])
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
vfunc(np.arange(len(values)))
# output: array([False, False,  True])
```

Comment: np.vectorize does **not** help with speed

Answer (score 1):

You've basically identified the two options:

```
In [35]: timeit [(i==a).any() for i,a in zip(values, arr)]                                     
29 µs ± 543 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [36]: timeit (values[:,None,None]==arr).any(axis=(1,2))                                     
11.4 µs ± 10.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

In this small case the big array approach is faster.  But for a larger case, the iteration might be better.  Memory management with the larger arrays may cancel out the time savings.  It's often the case that a few iterations on a complex problem are better than the fully 'vectorized' version.

If it's something you do repeatedly, you could take the time craft a hybrid solution, one that iterates on blocks.  But you'd have to judge that yourself.

`isin` and related code either `ors` some tests, or using `sort` of some sort to put like values next to each other for easy comparison.

The other approach is to write a fully iterative solution, and let `numba` compile it for you.

Comment: How about performance of vectorize method I used? Does it save time as to compare with previous way of looping?

Answer (score 1):

As hpaulj already mentioned `numba` can be an option here.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

#Turn off parallelization for tiny problems
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def example(values,arr):
    #Make sure that the first dimension is the same
    assert arr.shape[0]==values.shape[0]
    out=np.empty(values.shape[0],dtype=nb.bool_)

    for i in nb.prange(arr.shape[0]):
        out[i]=False
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            if arr[i,j]==values[i]:
                out[i]=True
                break
    return out
```

**Timings (small arrays)**

```
#your input data
%timeit example(values,arr.reshape(arr.shape[0],-1))# #parallel=True
#10.7 µs ± 34.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit example(values,arr.reshape(arr.shape[0],-1))# #parallel=False
#2.15 µs ± 49.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

#Methods from other answers
%timeit (values[:,None,None]==arr).any(axis=(1,2))
#9.52 µs ± 323 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit [(i==a).any() for i,a in zip(values, arr)]
#23.9 µs ± 435 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**Timings (larger arrays)**

```
values=np.random.randint(low=1,high=100_000,size=1_000_000)
arr=np.random.randint(low=1,high=10_00,size=1_000_000*100).reshape(1_000_000,10,10)

%timeit example(values,arr.reshape(arr.shape[0],-1)) #parallel=True
#48.2 ms ± 5.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit example(values,arr.reshape(arr.shape[0],-1)) #parallel=False
#90.5 ms ± 618 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#Methods from other answers
%timeit (values[:,None,None]==arr).any(axis=(1,2))
#186 ms ± 5.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit [(i==a).any() for i,a in zip(values, arr)]
#6.63 s ± 69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```